# Copy and Paste using Range.Copy Method

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, copy, copy-paste

I am trying to paste values from a bunch of tables into one long list. I have the tables spread across different sheets and the number of rows changes, but the columns do not. Then I am also trying to paste a string value that tells what sheet it came from, but having trouble with the active cell part of the code.

When I first tried it, it did not compile, hence why I came here, to figure out why it did not compile. Going back and forth with urdearboy, below, I was able to get the correct code working here.

I have the following:

```
sub copypaste()
  Dim ws1 as worksheet
  dim ws2 as worksheet
  dim mas as worksheet
  Set ws1 =ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
  Set ws2=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
  Set mas=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master") 'where I create my list

     For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> mas.Name Then
        LRow = mas.Range("A" & mas.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        wsLRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        ws.Range("A2:A" & wsLRow - 1).Copy
        mas.Range("A" & LRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        ws.Range("B2:B" & wsLRow - 1).Copy
        mas.Range("B" & LRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        mas.Range(mas.Cells(LRow, 4), mas.Cells(wsLRow + LRow - 2, 4)) = ws.Name 'I need my sheet value in the fourth column, not the third, but simply change the col coordinate in the Cells equation above

    End If
Next ws

'In order to figure out the sheet name, I used the following:
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = mas.Range("D2", Range("D2").End(xlDown))
For Each Cell In rng
    If Cell.Value = "Sheet 1" Then
        Cell.Value = "S1"
    ElseIf Cell.Value = "Sheet 2" Then
        Cell.Value = "S2"
    End If
Next Cell
```

end sub

Comment: This doesn't compile right now. Syntax errors

Comment: hence my issue with the copy and paste. It is not supposed to compile.

Comment: please see **how to include a [mcve]** with your question

Comment: Please explain what isn't working. Indicate any errors and on which lines they occur. Some sample data with expected output often helps.

Comment: I indicated where my error occurs within the code. There is no sample data as it is a values in excel.

Comment: @JackArmstrong you have syntax issues with your range on the error line. You can see one correct method on the solution below.

Comment: `Sheets(“Sheet1”).whatever` is how you access a sheet via string.

Comment: Please don’t add the answer in the question; this breaks the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will loop through **all** sheets, with the exception of `Master`, and import the values on Column A to `Master` accompanied by the origin of the data (sheet name).

`Option Explicit` for good measure.

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub copypaste()

Dim mas As Worksheet: Set mas = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master")
Dim ws As Worksheet, LRow As Long, wsLRow As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> mas.Name Then
            LRow = mas.Range("A" & mas.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
            wsLRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            ws.Range("A2:A" & wsLRow).Copy mas.Range("A" & LRow)
            mas.Range(mas.Cells(LRow, 2), mas.Cells(wsLRow + LRow - 2, 2)) = ws.Name
        End If
    Next ws
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

---

To paste values change

```
ws.Range("A2:A" & wsLRow).Copy mas.Range("A" & LRow)
```

to this

```
ws.Range("A2:A" & wsLRow).Copy
mas.Range("A" & LRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: anyway to add the sheet name as a string insteal of a variable? I have string names, but really need a short name for them, i.e. Sheet1=S1, Sheet2=S2. Sorry.

Comment: That is a separate ask from your original question. Give it a shot yourself and post a new question if you cannot figure it out! IF this does solve your initial ask, please clear question from unanswered queue by validating solution

Comment: Sounds like you know the sheet name references you want to use. Record a macro using the basic feature `CTRL + F` with Find / replace all

Comment: That's fair. What if I need to paste only the values? see edited above.

Comment: How did I change the question? Cause I asked to paste values instead? That's an update to the question, not changing it. There is no need to create a whole new thing for that. I edited the code. I will put down you as a contributor. Sorry about that.